# How to wait for results from a subshell in Bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline, subshell

I'm writing a helper function in Bash, whose task is to read some values from STDIN (one per line, like in `ls -1`) and then ask the user to pick one interactively. Before, I would use `dmenu`, but I wanted to make it more robust and provide for cases where there's no X11 present. I also preferred not to rely on some external tool, so I decided to make the shell built-in `select` my fallback mechanism. I wrote the following function:

```
function menu-selector {
    if ! xhost &> /dev/null; then
        cat | dmenu -l 10
    else
        select choice in $(cat); do
            echo $choice
            break
        done
    fi
}
```

Now, both branches work fine, when I use `menu-selector` in a pipeline, e.g.:

```
ls -1 | menu-selector
```

In both cases the appropriate mechanisms get invoked (`dmenu` or `select`) and the chosen value is returned by the function.
Trouble begins when I want to use my function somewhere in a subshell. Let's say I now want something like this:

```
my_dir=$(ls -1 | menu-selector)
echo $my_dir
```

In the X11 case `dmenu` pops up and waits for my action, upon which the selected value gets passed back to my code and gets printed. But when I go for the no-X11 option, `select` prints all options, but instead of waiting for my choice returns an empty value. What's the difference here and, more importantly, how can I make `select` work the same way, i.e. block execution of my script until it gets an answer from me. My guess is that the difference lies in the IO devices the two cases use - `dmenu` using the X root window and `select` using STDIN/OUT, perhaps being treated differently inside a subshell.

Comment: Very good Markdown formatting! Unfortunately Stack Overflow doesn't use the full MD flavor and instead use 4-space indentation for code blocks. I've edited it for you.

Comment: @iBug, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the standard input of the subshell running your menu function is filled with output from `ls -1`, so there's nothing for `select` to read.

Try using arguments instead of stdin to supply options so you don't mixup options and choice:

```
function menu-selector {
    if ! xhost &> /dev/null; then
        echo "$@" | dmenu -l 10
    else
        select choice in "$@"; do
            echo $choice
            break
        done
    fi
}
```

and use it like

```
response=$(menu-selector $(ls -1))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I lose the ability to use my function as a step in a pipeline. I tried using it with `xargs` instead, but this won't do. I also tried exporting my function, but `export -f <fun>` is not allowed in my script. Any ideas here?

Comment: You can do it the other way around. Read the std in first and pass that as a parameter.

Comment: @Woj You just change `whatever | menu-selector` into `menu-selector $(whatever)`, nothing else needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.